# How to call a generic method at runtime in typesafe way

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm trying to call a generic method at run time, and have working code. However, I was wondering if there was a better way of getting the method info, as should i change the method name, it will break.

```
public int Handle<T>(CreateCodeModel obj) where T : CodeModel
{
     //Create code here...
}

//codeType is selected by user.
public int Handle(CreateCodeModel obj, Type codeType)
{

    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Handle");
    //MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(mi => mi.IsGenericMethod && mi.Name == "Handle").First();

    MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { codeType });
    return (int)genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });

}
```

I had hoped there was a nicer way of doing this, perhaps using actions to get the method info, but then I still need to provide a type, e.g.

```
Action<CreateCodeModel> h = (x) => Handle(x);
MethodInfo method = h.Method;
```

Comment: At the very least, you could use `nameof` rather than a hard coded string. This way if the method is renamed you'll get a compiler error assuming tools such as R# or your IDE don't apply the refactoring for you.

Comment: Thanks, will do. But where I have overloaded methods, this will not cause compiler errors unless I rename both methods. Hence why I was hoping there was a way of using action or expression. But maybe this is not possible, or I am taking wrong approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track here.  Your delegate signature must match the method you are calling, so in this case that would be `Func<CreateCodeModel,int>` instead of `Action<CreateCodeModel>`.  And you must supply a generic parameter that matches the generic constraints.  This could be anything since we'll just remove it with our call to 'GetGenericMethodDefinition', but I like to use the class from the constraint.

The other piece of the code below is the idea that you only need to get the generic method definition once, as it doesn't change, so I store that in a static variable so it can be reused.

```
public int Handle<T>(CreateCodeModel obj) where T : CodeModel
{
    //Create code here...
    return 7;
}

// this static variable preserves the generic MethodInfo, so we don't have
// keep discovering it with reflection
private static MethodInfo _methodInfoForHandle;

// The generic MethodInfo only needs to be discovered the first time this runs
private MethodInfo MethodInfoForHandle
{
    get
    {
        return _methodInfoForHandle ?? (_methodInfoForHandle = GetMethodInfoForHandleMethod());
    }
}

private MethodInfo GetMethodInfoForHandleMethod()
{
    Func<CreateCodeModel, int> handleFunc = Handle<CodeModel>;
    return handleFunc.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
}


//codeType is selected by user.
public int Handle(CreateCodeModel obj, Type codeType)
{
    MethodInfo genericMethod = MethodInfoForHandle.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { codeType });
    return (int)genericMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });

}

public class CreateCodeModel { }
public class CodeModel { }
public class JavascriptCodeModel : CodeModel { }
```